# how to determine name/ip of primary network interface on centos x64 VPS

Tags: control-panel

I am trying to install Virtualmin - GPL on a Centos x64 VPS.

After downloading the script install.sh, I tried running it... At one stage this is the message that i received--

```
eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
INFO - Unable to determine IP address of primary interface.
Please enter the name of your primary network interface:
```

How do I determine the IP address/name of the primary network interface? Do I have to ask my web host about this information?

Thanks,
Arvind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eth0` is the most common ethernet device name, but it is not the only one, other device names are possible. Do this:

> route

On line which says `default` in the first column, the last column will be the device name you most probably need. Afterwards, run this:

> ifconfig `<devicename>`

Look for the value after `inet addr`, usually on line 2 of output. This is the IP address you're looking for.